# Where is the git repo under Xcode?

Tags: git, xcode5

I'm trying to use BFG to remove a bad commit with a large file. All the documents talk about the "repo" which is a file/folder with a `.git` extension. But this does not appear to exist on my computer. Where does Xcode hide the repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .git folder does exist. You can't see it because the Finder hides files and folders that start with a period, like the .git folder. There are utilities you can download to show hidden files in the Finder, like [Show Hide Invisible Files](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22318/show-hide-invisible-files). Or you can set it in the Terminal. A Google search for **show hide invisible files mac** brings up many articles on how to show hidden files in the Terminal, including the following:

[Quickly Show/Hide Hidden Files on Mac OS X Mavericks](http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/)

Where the .git folder resides depends on how you created your git repository. If you created an Xcode project and told Xcode to create a local repository, the .git folder will be inside your project folder.

Comment: Oddly, I *did* turn on hidden files display using the terminal command, and it didn't show up. Perhaps I did something else wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with the 'Terminal' application then you can find the `.git` folder with:

```
$ cd /Users/.../<path-to-project-folder>
$ ls -a
```

as in

```
$ cd /Users/ebg/.../project-name
$ ls -a 
./      .DS_Store   .gitignore  aman/       ...
../     .git/       ...
```